# ListItem as a submit button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use a `ListItem` as an upload button. I can't make the `handleSubmi`t to be called when `ListItem` is clicked. Below is my React component where I have a `Drawer` with a `List`.

How can I achieve that?

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <input
    accept="image/*"
    className={classes.input}
    id="raised-button-file"
    type="file"
    ref={input => { this.fileInput = input; }}
  />
  <label htmlFor="raised-button-file">
    <ListItem button type="submit">
      <ListItemIcon>
        <FileUploadIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Upload" />
    </ListItem>
  </label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the ListItem render a `li` component, change it to a `button`.
In order to trigger the form handler set the `submit` type.

```
<ListItem button type="submit" component="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use an `onClick` handler on the `ListItem` component like so:

```
<ListItem onClick={this.handleSubmit}/>
```